# Dropdown selected item and a Button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me with my problem I want to display result depends on the user wants they need to choose on 2 Dropdown list first and then they need to click the button to display the result

Here's what I have in html I have 2 Dropdown list and a button

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Choosy City <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">City 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">City 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">City 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">City 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            All Cuisine <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">24 hours</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">American</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Italian</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-left: 3px"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

any javascript jquery codes sorry I'm kind of new here

Comment: You'll have to try to write some jQuery code and post that here. Here's a fiddle that might get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/b6ydm/

Comment: What do you mean by result here? Do you want selected value from both dropdown menu?

Comment: yes sir, then user will be directed to another page

Comment: *" I want to display result depends on the user wants they need to choose on 2 Dropdown list first and then they need to click the button to display the result"* - i didn't understand anything from that. BTW, what have you tried? if you expect somebody else to write the code for you, you'll be always *kind of new*

Comment: sorry not good in english, I'm searching some answer for my problem and I tried to ask a question here

Comment: @user3667305: Just for confirmation, you are using pure HTML or asp.net, php?

Comment: html sir I'm using Brackets editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `HTML option Tag` ([see example here](http://www.webblogsforyou.com/html-option-tag-with-example/) with example) instead `ul li` (as you are beginner) and then use jQuery to get selected value or text.

**For example:**

HTML:

```
<select id="optCity">
<option value="MH">Maharastra</option>
<option value="GJ">Gujarat</option>
<option value="MP">Madhya Pradesh</option>
</select>
<button id="btnClick" type="button">Choosy City</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnClick').click(function(event) {
        alert($('#optCity option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9yke1y46/).

**Suggestion:** You should start some basic learning about jquery from w3cschool.com.

`UPDATE2:`

here is the answer to your next question.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnClick').click(function(event) {
        //alert($('#optCity option:selected').text());
        window.location.assign("your url here");
    });
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9yke1y46/1/).

Comment: 1 more, I want to be directed to another page instead of using alert ?

Comment: see my answer `UPDATE2` for your question.